# Unexpected token import with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I'd like to store my Vue templates into variables so I can route them.

I created an App.vue file containing only a HTML title (for testing purposes), and a main.js file with an 'import' command that I never used in JavaScript, but I don't know any other way to get a template file's content into a variable, knowing that every documentation tell to do like that.

Anyway, with this 'import' command I get this error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

And here's the import line: "import App from '../vues/App';"

I checked the path, it's ok, but if you know any other way to get a template file's content into a JS variable, let me know.

Thank you for your attention.

EDIT:
main.js

```
import App from '../vues/App';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
});
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your main.js code? In javascript `import` does place a code file into the scope as well as its result in a variable. in this case, `App` is the variable to hold the resulting object from `../vues/App`. Have you tried exporting a blank component set in your .vue file? `<script>export default {}</script>` after your `<template></template>` call

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my post. I tried with export defaut, but the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

You are using es6 syntax ( import ) and your environment only support es5 syntax. So either configure "babel" in your webpack or use require instead of import

```
var App = require( "../vues/App" );
```

UPDATE: this error could also appear in case you do not have a module bundler installed, such as Webpack which takes modules with dependencies and generates static assets representing those modules.
install it from here : https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: I've installed webpack with npm, I don't know which file to link in index.html in order to make require work, node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js uses require itself